# How to not repeat this code when animating vs not animating?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Observe this code:

```
- (void)hideRectangleWithAnimation:(BOOL)animate completion:(void (^)(void))completionBlock
{
    if (animate)
    {
        // Hide rectangle
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{ rect.alpha = 0; } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            completionBlock();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        rect.alpha = 0;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to not repeat the property change: `rect.alpha = 0;` twice?

This line of code is currently trivial but there could be a more complex case where multiple stuff are happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just found the answer. I can put `rect.alpha = 0;` in a block variable and use that instead.

```
void (^animationBlock)(void) = ^{
    rect.alpha = 0;
};

if (animate)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:animationBlock completion:^(BOOL finished){
        completionBlock();
    }];
}
else
{
    animationBlock();
}
```

Comment: That was one way I was thinking of.  Another might be to try switching the duration for animating between 0.0f or 0.3f, if that suits your needs.

Comment: @MatthewGillingham Although, if duration is 0, would it happen instantaneously or would it run on a separate thread or next execution cycle?

Comment: I am not one-hundred percent sure, but I think animateWithDuration: is run on a separate thread, so setting the duration to 0.0f would likely run on a separate thread as well.  I  wasn't trying to suggest that the solutions were identical, only that the other one might be good enough to suit your needs.

Comment: Setting duration to 0 could have other side-effects as well. I think the completion block _will_ run in that case, which is different from the code above. Also, it will _cancel_ any ongoing animation to the rect.alpha property, whereas setting rect.alpha = 0 without animation will cause the ongoing animation to continue but proceed toward 0. (I.e., if it was a 3s animation from alpha 0.5 to 1.0, and you set rect.alpha = 0 after 1.5s, then you will get 1.5s of animation from 0.75 to 0.0.)

Comment: Yes, I agree that setting the duration to 0.0f would have those different side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:animate];
[UIView animationWithDuration:...];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

I'm not sure if it will run the completion block in either case or not.